# How to mask triangle out of the video strip in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

Im struggling with masking portions out of my video in VSE. I need to mask two triangles at each side of the video, because when positioned next to each other in 90 degrees angle (via transform layers), the corners will overlay each other and ulimately obstruct the view of the other video.

So in another words I need to have 4 same videos but cut the corners of each. I think this can be solved by some masking but I did not find the answer yet.

Thanks, Mike

*I need to mask red parts, but how?*
[image: see example below]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use create a Mask (in an **UV/Image Editor** set to **Mask** *Mode*) covering the content you want to keep. You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click to add Points to create a Mask and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to *Toggle Cyclic* so that the first and last point are connected. Use <kbd>V</kbd> to *Set Handle Type*s if needed.
2. Set your *Transform Effect Strip*s **Blend type** *Properties* (<kbd>N</kbd>) each to **Alpha Over**. Oh and you'd better mute (<kbd>H</kbd>) your underlying Video Strips when you use an Effect Strip on top to reduce unwanted side effects.
3. Use that Mask going to the **Modifiers** *Properties* of your Video Strip in the VSE, click **Add Strip Modifier**, set it to **Mask** instead of **Strip** (Type of input data) and select your Mask created in Step 1.

[image: Example of masking four images together]

Comment: Hello Samoth, thank you for your great answer. I have managed to apply mask on my strip. However one thing is still not clear. Do you have to create 4 masks or you are using the same one?

Comment: You can select the same mask many times... no problem. As your Video Strip is just a duplicate you can use the same mask again and again. There's even a **Copy to Selected Strips** Button to help you copy your complete Mask Modifier around. Just select the one to be copied from last.

Comment: You can see in my example image that in the UV/Image Editor there is a "6" next to "MyMask". This means, it's currently being used 6 times. So no need to create the same mask more than once.

Comment: mhmm, but when I apply the mask onto the next strip the same area is displayed. So how do you managed to "rotate" also the mask together with the strip?

Comment: As you should be able to see, and as I wrote, I added the Mask Modifier to the Video Strip, not to the Transform Effect Strip.

Comment: you are a star, thank you. I got it now. I was applying the mask to transform layer only. Now when applied onto the video strip it has worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33722/discussion-between-miroslav-slavik-and-samoth).